# What is the scope of damages in common law fraud?

Tags: california, fraud, consumer-protection, common-law, tort

It appears to me that in case of fraud, the benefit-of-the-bargain rule defines the breadth and width of the liability of the tortfeasor in some U.S. states, and not strict liability.

Do I understand correctly that whatever causation is present between the loss of the benefit of the bargain (say financial gains) and whatever results from, for e.g., such loss of financial gains will be beyond the benefit-of-the-bargain liability scope? In such causation chain, can one say this sort of “secondary loss” caustic loss is not “naturally flowing” from the tort?

EXAMPLE:

You buy a car that you agreed to pay $800 a month only for the dealer to then charge your bank payments each month $1,700 enough for you to no longer afford housing, or else, declare bankruptcy and have the bank repossess the car. Then the fraud leads to various harms and damages including non-economic.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? "I got defrauded of $X,000 in my bank account, and as a result of that I lost my house" or something?

Comment: Added a close-enough example!

Comment: Please explain the discrepancy between the $800/month agreement and the $1700/month charge.  What does the financing agreement say?

Comment: @jwh20 Presumably, that would be the fraud.

Comment: The question is very unclear.  Hence my inquiry.

Comment: @jwh20 it’s a hypothetical: You can fill it in pretty much with anything that would result in common law fraud in California. The agreement says $800/mo and, without further agreement, the other party collects $1700/mo.